# Can I inspect my rental property in between lease terms?

Tags: united-states, rental-property, pennsylvania

I have tenants in a rental property (in Philadlephia, PA) who are going to be renewing their yearly lease. Am I allowed to request/dictate a visual inspection of the property as a conditional requirement for the renewal? If not, am I just supposed to perpetually hope that they’re not destroying the place on the inside until they decide not to renew?

Comment: Did you not write into the lease that you can access the property for maintenance, repairs, etc, upon giving them sufficient advance notice?  Maintenance usually involves inspection...

Comment: I cant answer as I dont know the applicable law  but, at least when I was involved in renting in NZ, many/most insurance companies REQUIRED periodic inspections of the property.  Rights around inspecting properties were written into the law.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Your lease should contain terms on periodic inspections

It is completely normal for a lease to allow the landlord to inspect periodically, usually at six-monthly intervals.

Comment: There should be some rules though, in my area the landlord cannot enter the property without the renters presence, it must be done at the renters convenience and cannot happen more than once a month, but generally the landlord must completely allow the reasonable enjoyment of the property by the renter